# Office-js: Excel addin failed to load when reopening the excel file

Tags: office-js

We noticed the add-in failed when a file is reopened. The reopen I mean:

- Open a new, Add add-in (which works fine)
- Save a file
- Reopen the file. Then the Add-in failed with “Add-in Warning  This add-in is not available in Office Online.”

All the browsers (i.e., Excel online) and iPad Excel scenarios failed and others are ok.

Is this an known issue?

Comment: When you are adding an add-in to a new file, which Add-in are you adding, and how?  Where is the manifest that's being pointed to by the document?  (VS F5, network share, ?...)

Comment: Currently we use side-loading. When we first loaded the addin, we uploaded the manifest from a local machine. BTW, we are talking about Excel Online. not the desktop.